# MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014 SQL Export breaks

Tags: sql-server, export, ssms, sql-server-2012-express

i'm having issues with the Script Generation task of SSMSS.
My initial idea is to export an existing database from MS SQL 2012 Express to a SQL-File to be able to import it in a later step via a .NET application.

The issues i'm facing is, that the generation outputs scripts which are breaking the SQLClient used in C#.

E.g something like this returns an exception that there are more values to be inserted than actual columns are.
This is based on a wrong interpretation of the Margin column which value is exported to 0,17 and not 0.17

```
INSERT [dbo].[ProductServiceSystemSet] ([Id], [CreatedAt], [Sold], [ConfigurationFinished], [Margin], [Cost], [Designator], [deleted], [SecondLifeScenario_Id]) VALUES (12, CAST(N'2009-07-04 00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 0, 1, 0,17, NULL, N'Variante 2', NULL, 6)
```

Is this issue known? How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find it.
My SQL Server has been installed with German Language. Somehow the locales broke the sql export.
I've deinstalled the German one and installed the English one.
Works since then